# JS, unit testing : expect on a callback

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, leaflet

I am using Leaflet, and I am creating a marker on it. Once the mouse is out of this marker, I would like to remove the pop-up I am displaying on `mouseenter` :

```
marker.on('mouseout', e => this.leafletMap.closePopup());
```

In my testing, I would like to know if the callback provided is what I expect.

I already test if the event happens on mouseout with

```
expect((mockedMarker.on as jasmine.Spy).calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toEqual('mouseover');
```

Any ideas on how to do that ?

I tried something like this

```
expect((mockedMarker.on as jasmine.Spy).calls.argsFor(0)[1]).toEqual(JSON.stringify(component.leafletMap.closePopup));
```

But I don't know what I'm doing (I'm new to unit testing), and I can't find a solution online because I don't really know how to call this kind of test.

I should state that I work in **Typescript**.

Comment: how about `expect((mockedMarker.on as jasmine.Spy).calls.argsFor(0)[1].toString()).toEqual("e => this.leafletMap.closePopup()"));` ?

Comment: The `toEqual` would be a string ? Because when I tested it, the type of variable to expect was a function ...

Comment: expect is a generic interface and it can take a lot of things. I would suggest you give it a shot. Basically you want to get the function that was passed and do a toString and get the lambda definition. Though this is honestly not needed but just because you insist to do it, I am providing a solution. This may not be a Unit test by definition

Comment: No, that's not what I meant :D I already tried that, with a different string, and the output was "expect [myString] to equal Function". And I agree that this isn't a unit test, I just want my files to have a hundred percent coverage. I just don't know how to cover this lambda ...

Comment: Can you take `(mockedMarker.on as jasmine.Spy).calls.argsFor(0)[1]` into a variable and see what exactly are you getting? And if `toString()` on the same gives you the lambda def. If yes then break this into two steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you want to test is that the function callback does what you want it to.  For that, you should not be checking the function string. That test would be too brittle.

Instead, you should check that when you invoke the callback, the leaflet is closed. Here is a simple test for that. It assumes that you have properly scaffolded the marker, the leaflet, and the callback:

```
describe('Marker', () => {
    it('should invoke closePopup', () => {
        let marker = createMarkerWithLeaflet();
        spyOn(marker, 'on');
        spyOn(marker.leaflet, 'closePopup');

        marker.on.calls.argsFor(0)[1]();
        expect(marker.leaflet.closePopup).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not a unit test and but since you want to test I would give a solution. Below is a sample jasmine script I worked out for you

```
let marker = function() {
    function on(a, b) {
        console.log(a, b);
    }

    this.on = on;
}
describe('this', () => {
    it('xya', () => {
        y = new marker()
        spyOn(y, 'on');
        y.on('onmouseout', e => this.leafletMap.closePopup());
        const lambda = y.on.calls.argsFor(0)[1]
        console.log(lambda.toString())
        expect(lambda.toString()).toEqual("e => this.leafletMap.closePopup()")
    })
})
```

Running on terminal

```
$ npx jasmine mocking.js
Randomized with seed 33786
Started
e => this.leafletMap.closePopup()
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.006 seconds
Randomized with seed 33786 (jasmine --random=true --seed=33786)
```